# Removing Form Feed character from first line

Tags: oracle10g, sqlplus

I've got a unix shell that runs a script SQL by using SQLPLUS .
At the top of the SQL I've got some istructions like

```
set pagesize 1000
set scan off
set feedback off
set linesize 3000
set heading off
set newpage 0
```

and after my query begins
but in the output at the beginning of the first line I've got Form Feed Character and this is a problem because I'm creating a CSV file

```
FF2156747,2019,06-JUL-20,30,E,GE,99,2019,1,1,A,967,,53617
2156749,2019,06-JUL-20,30,E,GE,99,2019,2,2,A,967,5361
2156751,2019,06-JUL-20,30,E,GE,99,2019,7,7,A,201,39477,1
...
```

Oracle version 10g

Thanks in advance

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
set newpage 0
```

do:

```
set newpage none
```

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-B7D1FFE5-9FFE-43C3-B52B-6DCCBCC3AA03), `newpage`:

> Sets the number of blank lines to be printed from the top of each page to the top title. A value of zero places a formfeed at the beginning of each page (including the first page) and clears the screen on most terminals. If you set NEWPAGE to NONE, SQL*Plus does not print a blank line or formfeed between the report pages.